# Is is possible to use ssh-copy-id without server password logging enabled

Tags: ssh, public-key

I wish to add a new public key to my servers authorized_keys file. Is it possible to add a new public key without enabling password authentication for `ssh-copy-id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have another key handy to log into the server, then yes – otherwise, I think you're stuck.

(Just think about it – the server has to authenticate you *somehow*. If you won't use a password, and if you haven't any older authorized keys yet, the server can't let you in just like that.)